# Starting a program minimized via Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, minimized

I have been searching around on a way to do this, but the `/min` command does not start my MP3 file minimized.

Here is the code:

`start /min song1.mp3 "cd /d %~dp0"`

The program I'm using to play the MP3 is Windows Media Player.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot start the media player minimized when letting play a music track.

But you can start Windows Media Player minimized:

```
start /min wmplayer.exe
```

Here you can see command line parameters for wmplayer.exe:

[Command Line Parameters for Wmplayer](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDIQFjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fwindows%2Fdesktop%2Fdd562624%2528v%3Dvs.85%2529.aspx&ei=2cu_VP7PLMH0UpWvg-AH&usg=AFQjCNESKhRxrr_s9E8wNuMEb7VSt-mxEg&sig2=LCiEhTDu9ZQ9tsBYN84WXg&bvm=bv.83829542,d.d24)

If you want to play a music track use that instead:

```
start wmplayer.exe "C:\Path\To\Music\track.mp3"
```

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. WMPlayer does not start minimized :(

Comment: Could  you use Powershell and `Start-Process WMPlayer.exe -ArgumentList "Song.MP3" -WindowStyle Minimized`

Answer (score 0):

You can use VLC player

1. Open Tools -> Preferences
2. Click on All settings (left bottom)
3. Interface
4. Main Interface
5. Select Qt interface from the Interface Module Drop-down (right side)
6. Now on the left-hand page, expand Main Interface
7. Click Qt
8. Check Start VLC with only a system tray icon